# message publishing using kombu - TypeError 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django, kombu

After encoding my message payload to json, I'm attempting to publish to the broker with:

```
connection = establish_connection()
producer = Producer(channel=connection,
                      exchange="inbound",
                      routing_key="apisubmit")

producer.publish(body=pl,headers={"api_access_key": "xxxx", "client_id": 4, "object_type": "location", "action": "c"})
```

django is returning the following:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/pythonenv/openblock/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/pythonenv/openblock/src/myblock/myblock/barz/views.py" in testtwo
  19.     msg=publish_kombu()
File "/usr/local/pythonenv/openblock/src/myblock/myblock/barz/messaging.py" in publish_kombu
  99.                           routing_key="apisubmit")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py" in __init__
  82.         self.exchange = self.exchange(self.channel)

Exception Type: TypeError at /barz/publish_kombu/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

`Producer.exchange` must be an `Exchange`.  By default it's `Exchange("")`, somehow you must have set it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you be passing value to '**exchange**' param it has to be an `Exchange` object.

Your code has to be:

```
exchange = Exchange(name='inbound') # the minimal declaration
connection = establish_connection()
producer = Producer(channel=connection,
                      exchange=exchange,
                      routing_key="apisubmit")

producer.publish(body=pl,headers={"api_access_key": "xxxx", "client_id": 4, "object_type": "location", "action": "c"})
```

For full list of Exchange param - [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/reference/kombu.html#kombu.Exchange).

---

I encountered the same error at queue declaration i.e.

```
queue = Queue(name=queue_name, exchange='host_tasks', routing_key=binding_key)
bound_queue = queue(channel) # only once bound, we can call declare(), purge(), delete() on exchange
```

So declared an Exchange, such thah

```
exchange = Exchange('host_tasks', 'direct', durable=True)
queue = Queue(name=queue_name, exchange=exchange, routing_key=binding_key)
bound_queue = queue(channel)
```

Don't forget to `import Exchange`